# mysql: order by calculatet_value

Tags: mysql

I am getting stuck with a MySQL query...

I have reconstructed a simple example:

```
SELECT
username,
if(username is null, 'anonym', 'is_set') as checker,

if(checker = 'anonym', 'a', 'b') as checker_test

FROM

v1_users

order by checker_test
```

but I am getting the error

unknown column 'checker_test' in field list.

I wonder why this is happening because this query is working:

```
SELECT 
username,
if(username != '', username, 'anonym') as my_value

FROM `v1_users`

order by my_value
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include at least 1) a complete SQL query rather than separate fragments; 2) the *exact* error message you are getting. Ideally, also provide a sample schema to make a [mre] (see [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/157957)).

Comment: You cannot use output column alias in the expression for another output column (rather then source column name in your "this query is working"). Either use column expression one more time or move the query to subquery or CTE and reuse the column value in outer query.

Comment: but if i have to calculate values depending on other values what would be the best way? variables?